# Blank screen appears in tablet for jquery apps :

Tags: jquery, android

recently i have created an application RSS reader using jquery, integrated with android, while running the application in phone it works, but on tablet it shows blank screen randomly (7/10). Is this because of error in the code..

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to debug it step by step & put some code so that we can find what happened.

to go first:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //render some debug text on main window
});
```

Comment: i have given alert in all possible functions and checked, but wonder why it happens only for tablets,that too randomly..

Comment: Hi guys, when adding drop down box in a div a back button automatically adds to the header in jquery , y is it so ?